# rapidjson writer generate extra braces

Tags: c++

I just try to use rapidjson.
And write some code to translate code into string.

```
Document dd;
dd.SetObject();

Value num(kNumberType);
num.SetInt(23);

dd.AddMember("number", num, dd.GetAllocator());

GenericStringBuffer< UTF8<> > buffer;
Writer<GenericStringBuffer< UTF8<> > > writer(buffer);

dd.Accept(writer);

// use writer
writer.StartObject();
writer.EndObject();

printf("%s\n", buffer.GetString());
```

The output is

```
{"number":23}{}
```

It's weird to get extra braces after the object body. But it works good with pretty writer.

```
StringBuffer buffer;
PrettyWriter<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
dd.Accept(writer);
printf("%s\n", buffer.GetString());
```

I got result like this:

```
{
"number": 23
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `dd.Accept(writer)` is called, the DOM is stringify to the writer.

Afterwards, calling `writer.StartObject()` and `writer.EndObject()` just write another empty object using SAX-like API (i.e. writing the "extra braces").

So the output contains the DOM output and the SAX output. And this is the expected output.